# Setting a default value to an indexed pyomo parameter

Tags: dataframe, parameters, pyomo, indexed

I got a dataframe which looks like following:

```
>data
         x     y
Name                              
A        NaN   0
B        65,2  NaN
C        NaN   100
```

I create a pyomo Set-Object `m.index`, for indexing a mutable pyomo Parameter-Object `m.parameter_y`.

**`m.index`:**

```
# code
m.index = pyomo.Set(
    initialize=data.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
    doc='Index Set')

# output
(Pdb) m.index.pprint()
index : Index Set
    Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Mutable=True, Bounds=None
    ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

**`m.parameter_y`:**

```
# code
m.parameter_y = pyomo.Param(
    m.index,
    default=data['y'].values,
    mutable=True
    doc='Par y')

# output
(Pdb) m.parameter_y.pprint()
parameter_y : Par y
    Size=3, Index=index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=True
    Key : Value
    A   : [  0   nan   100. ]
    B   : [  0   nan   100. ]
    C   : [  0   nan   100. ]
```

As you can see using `default=df['y'].values`, gets all the values of the column `y` as a value of the parameter.

**How would I set the values of a mutable indexed pyomo Parameter-Object if I wanted to expect following output?**

```
(Pdb) m.parameter_y.pprint()
parameter_y : Par y
    Size=3, Index=index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=True
    Key : Value
    A   : [  0  ]
    B   : [ nan ]
    C   : [ 100 ]
```

PS: Keep in mind this isn't the actual dataframe, index-set, or the parameter. So Answers like adding values somehow manually won't work in my case. What would work, some kind of a better value-getting-function from a dataframe, so that, I can set these values on that parameter as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the parameter values to be singleton values and not a list, the following should work:

```
m.parameter_y = pyomo.Param(
    m.index,
    default=data['y'].to_dict(),
    mutable=True
    doc='Par y')
```

Is there a reason you are using the `default` argument instead of `initialize`?

Comment: I am planning to change some of the values through some for loop iterations. But some of the values will be untouched. Initialize probably would do the same trick. Do you suggest me to use initialize instead of default, if yes why? Ps: I am going to check the answer later. ty bethany

Comment: When you're working with mutable Params it doesn't matter which you use but I think it's more common to use `initialize` for your use-case. If you were using immutable Params then there would be a difference in maintaining sparsity, `initialize` automatically constructs any indices for which you provide values and `default` will be checked for valid indices that have not been constructed but will not construct missing indices.